# Passing options and parameters to Test/Unit via Rake::TestTask

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, webdriver, rake

So I've been trying to figure this out, and the best solution I can came up with his global variables - but that seems so dirty and 1974 - Am I missing a feature of Rake/ Test::Unit?

**I have a Rake file in which I'm running tests:**

```
Rake::TestTask.new(:test) do |t|
t.test_files = FileList['test_*.rb']
end
```

**and test_1.rb has something like this:**

```
require "test/unit"
class TestStuff < Test::Unit::TestCase
    def setup
              @thingy = Thing.New(parameter1, parameter2)
    end

    def test_this_thing
              @thing.do()
    end

end
```

My problem is, Thing.new() requires arguments, and those arguments are specific to my environment. In reality, I'm running Selenium-WebDriver, and I want to pass in a browser type, and a url, etc... sometimes I want ff, othertimes I want chrome... sometimes this URL, sometimes that... depending on the day, etc.

**The simplest thing *seems* to do something like:**

```
#all that rake stuff
$parameter1 = x
$parameter2 = y
```

**and then make Thing.new() look up my global vars:**

```
        @thingy = Thing.New($parameter1, $parameter2)
```

This seems sloppy.. and it just doesn't feel right to me. I'm still trying to get this 'test harness' up and running, and want to do it right the first time. That's why I chose Rake, based on a lot of other feedback.

Keep in mind, I'll probably have 100's of tests, ultimately, and they'll all need to do get this information... I thought Rake was good at making sure all of this was easy, but it doesn't seem to be.

**Where did I go wrong?**

Answer (score 1):

I have used YAML files to store my configuration (browser config, environments including URLs, etc).

You can also use an environmental variable to define simple configurations. You can access environmental variables via `ENV['foobar']` in Ruby.

So, for example, my browser call might look like this inside my setup method:

```
 driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for (ENV['SWD_BROWSER'] || "firefox").to_sym
```

and in my Rake file (or in the shell console) define the environmental variable to use.

Comment: I want to run tests multi-threaded.  It seems that this method would be a problem if I were doing that, especially if every test took different values for the options.